# Selenium: Check if the test failed

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

is it possible to check if the current test failed in Selenium IDE (or RC)? For example is there a variable like `passed=true` which can be as accessed via `storedVars.passed`

I need this information for an if statement.

```
If storedVars.passed then
   DO SOMETHING
ELSE
   EXIT
END
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use assertValue or verifyValue to do so

command:assertValue

target:storedVars.passed

value:true

assert value will stop the execution whereas verify value will give the error and run the next command

i hope this section helps you or give you little idea about how to work with if-statement